# how to get salary grade with salary range in forms?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms

i am working in oracle forms with schema Scott and i want to make another block to view the grade for each employee based on every employee salary from employee table and salary range from salary grade table how could i do it ?

Comment: The easiest way is to create a view in the database that do the SQL hassle, and then build your block in forms against the view.

Comment: i tried but not working look
create or replace view v_grade as 
Select salgrade.grade, salgrade.losal, salgrade.hisal, emp.sal,EMP.ENAME,EMP.EMPNO,EMP.COMM,EMP.DEPTNO from EMP, salgrade
Where emp.sal between salgrade.losal and salgrade.hisal;

Comment: What is not working? Are you not able to create the view or is it returning the wrong values;

Comment: i am trying to create function to get it in forms

Comment: And that is possible also but less easy. What you need is to put the where statement into the WHERE clause of the salgrade block and use the empsal from the current record in the EMP block.

Comment: i did it thank you too much

Comment: when i create view it gives me error 
ORA-01031

Comment: ORA-1031 means "lack of privilege" so you don't have "create view" privilege in the scott schema.

Comment: yes thanks very much for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two `Data Blocks` for `emp` and `salgrade` tables with `Data Block Wizard` [ those ( `emp` and `salgrade` ) may be left as block names, also ].

Add this string `:emp.sal between losal and hisal` into `WHERE Clause` of salgrade block.

And then create a `WHEN-NEW-ITEM-INSTANCE` trigger at block level for `emp` with the code below :

```
go_block('salgrade');
execute_query;
go_block('emp');
```

Whenever a query executed in the `emp` block, a query synchronously executed for `salgrade` block that brings the range for the grades matching with `salary` column of `emp`.